# Help needed to calculate distance of equal pixel distribution

Tags: measurement

I came across a layout with a mathematical problem. I have made all my shapes to have 3 pixel gap between them, the problem I'm facing is:

1)3 Green squares are 17x17px,but I'm left with 1px gap. (Where Red arrow is pointing).

2)Teal colour boxes 30x30px and do have 3 pixels gap, but obviously they're too big. So they go beyond the boundaries of the Orange square. Need to fit them within the Orange square with 3 pixel gap.

I cant figure out how to correct this problem. What do I need to calculate first so all the shapes can have 3px distance between them.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: There are several measurement errors in your example image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

The short answer is that what you want probably isn't possible with the given measurements. You are working within a pixel grid which is by definition completely rigid. Every length has to be an integer (a whole number). You will often encounter these situations where the numbers simply don't add up. Then you'll have to either adjust the whole drawing or live with a box being a tile wider or narrower than it should ideally be.

### Measurement confusion

First I have to address that the illustration you are showing is filled with errors. Actually none of the numbers are correct. This confused me and is probably confusing you as well.

You've swapped the numbers for the total width and height (`148 px` and `446 px`). And `446 px` seems to be a typo. In your AI file it measures 464 px.

The blue box in the top right is said to be `68 x 39 px`, but in the file the width is 60 px.

Besides these typos, all your measurements are 1 px off.

[image]

You are using a 1 px stroke aligned to center. So in reality all your boxes are 1 px wider and 1 px taller than you think.

I think for this kind of drawing I would align the strokes to the inside to make it easier to understand. Also makes the boxes simpler to draw as their positions don't have to be offset by 0.5 px.

### Dividing a length into segments

Dividing a length `l` into a number `n` of segments of equal length `s` is easy:

`s = l / n`

But if everything has to snap to a grid, `n` must be a divisor of `l`.

In other words: The length divided by the number of segments must be a whole number.

#### Example

As an example we can look at the number 12, which is interesting because it has a six divisors: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 12. If we set `l = 12` we get:

[image]

Its neighbor 11 is a prime number so it only has two divisors: 1 and 11. If we set `l = 11` we get:

[image]

### Dividing a length into segments with gaps

If we add a gap `g` between the sections into the mix we get a slightly more complex equation:

`s = (l - (n - 1) * g) / n`

Now `n` must be a divisor of `l - (n - 1) * g`.

(If we set `g = 0` we're back to the equation we had before.)

#### Example

If we add a gap to the example from before by setting `g = 1`, the number 12 is suddenly a bad choice.

If we insert the variables we have into `l - (n - 1) * g` and reduce it, we get that `n` must be a divisor of `13 - n`. This is only true for `n = 1`.

[image]

The number 11 is a much better choice.

Here `n` must be a divisor of `12 - n` and that happens numerous times.

[image]

### The specific case

In your specific case you want to be able to divide a length of 61 px into both 2 and 3 segments with a 3 px gap.

So we must set `g = 3` and look for a value for `l` close to `61` where the expression `l - (n - 1) * g` has both `n = 2` and `n = 3` as divisors.

By inserting the values in the equation and reducing, we find that we must find a value for `l` where both `(l - 3) / 2` and `(l - 6) / 3` is an integer.

By manually testing numbers around 61, I find that this is true for `l = 57` and `l = 63`.

[image]

[image]

### Links

- Read about [divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) at Wikipedia. The article has a table of divisors which can be used to find the "magic" numbers.
- I made [a simple tool](http://madswolff.dk/projects/Grid%20With%20Gaps/) for my own use to ease finding the divisors with a given length and gap which you might find useful.

Comment: Wow, I cannot thank you enough for this answer. Such a reply in response helped me understand about planning and calculating. Kind regards.

Comment: @blenderbreath, that's good to hear! You're welcome.